# Downloading files using Java randomly freezes

Tags: java, io

When I try to download a file (in this case it's just an image but the real application is an updating mechanism), the `InputStream` seems to freeze on `read`. I'm pretty sure my code is okay, so I'm wondering why this happens and if it's just on my computer. Could someone please run this? Please note that the `Timer` is simply for debugging purposes.

Thank you kindly.

Here is a video showing the problem: [Video](http://dev.fhmp.net/java/SO_demo.swf)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FileDownloader {

    public final static int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1 << 14;

    private static Timer timeoutTimer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Timeout");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        URL url = new URL("http://host.trivialbeing.org/up/tdk-aug3-jokr-high-res-2.jpg");
        download(url, new File("joker.jpg"));
    }

    public static void download(final URL url, final File dest) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        int bytesRead;
        int bytesWritten = 0;
        timeoutTimer.start();
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1) {
            timeoutTimer.restart();
            out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            out.flush();
            bytesWritten += bytesRead;
            System.out.println(bytesWritten / 1024 + " kb written");
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Finished");
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran it 10x in a row without a problem.

Comment: I just tried the code on my system and had no problem downloading the joker at all :).  This is on XUbuntu 12.4 with the IcedTea 6 JRE.  The only thing that occurs to me is to flush the output stream in the loop -- but I don't see how this would change anything.

Comment: I'll try that. It freezes almost every time I try it though!

Comment: What OS and java are you running?  This could be a platform specific issue.  Or it could just be your Internet connection...

Comment: Well I just played a few games of Dota 2 and I'm clearly on SO so I doubt it's my connection. Though is it possible that I could be losing connection for an instant? Which may cause the stream to stop. I'm running Java 7 on Windows 7.

Comment: It's probably not the Internet then.  How do you know that it's in.read() which is causing the problem?

Comment: I spammed the loop with System.out.println's and it stopped at the end of the loop, ie. the start.

Comment: This problem sounds very similar to the one I asked on SuperUser - it contains an really interesting answer: http://superuser.com/questions/410883/downloads-stops-tcp-window-full

Comment: I had to add my proxy server, but it works for me on Win7, Java 1.7.0_05 64-bit

Comment: @Robert Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Works beautifully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are facing is caused by Java 7 - in detail that to gives IPv6 a higher priority than IPv4.

You can change it back to IPv4 as it was used in Java 6 by setting the system property `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");`

This problem affects all Java based software but only occurs on some computers (may depend on the internet connection used): [Downloads stops - “TCP Window Full”](https://superuser.com/questions/410883/downloads-stops-tcp-window-full)

Answer (score 0):

O.K I think it's a laggy system or what by the guy who answered above me (Robert I think)
but using ipv6 is going to be hard if you already no about ipv4 a lot.

Just a coincedence I'm named Robert :)