# Java ImageIcon.GetImage hanging

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

I am having trouble with ImageIcon().GetImage()

The strange thing is, is that it sometimes works and shows me the window with the maps on it, and other times it doesn't. It also works on other computers flawlessly but not on mine!

I have tried everything, reinstalling Java, reinstalling IntelliJ, also disabling my firewall, but to no avail. I have also written a similar program in C# which works perfectly, which leads me to believe it isn't a permissions error. I have also tested it on a basic Windows XP system with an on board graphics card which also works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Running main..");
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.80382155278416,18.567184266922002&zoom=17&size=1024x1024&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false&format=png&key=AIzaSyCVnp9iTXRSS3ZE5FjzF7uNZavazWhLko4");
        Image img=new ImageIcon(url).getImage();
        System.out.println("INFO :"+img);
        new ImageFrame(img);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class ImageFrame extends JFrame{

    public ImageFrame(Image img){

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(540, 480));
        setaImg(img);
        ImagePanel somePanel = new ImagePanel(540, 480);
        add(somePanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private Image aImg;

    public Image getaImg() {
        return aImg;
    }

    public void setaImg(Image aImg) {
        this.aImg = aImg;
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

        public ImagePanel(int width, int height){
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(getaImg(), 0, 0, null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters
        }
    }



}

 }
```

I have ran it through the step through debugger and it stops at this line:

```
Image img=new ImageIcon(url).getImage();
```

But with no error, it just hangs forever.

I am totally confused as to why it isn't working on my system, and only my system. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: `ImageIcon.GetImage`  -> `NoSuchMEthodError` DYM `ImageIcon.getImage`?  If so, be sure to use correct capitals, otherwise we are likely to guess that an extended (and bug ridden) implementation of `ImageIO` is being used.

Comment: Why not add the `ImageIcon` to a `JLabel` to display it?

Comment: `ImageFrame extends JFrame`  Don't extend frame, just use an instance of one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works fine for me

[image]

Google's not blocking you are they?  From memory you have something like 10,000 queries a day or something.

Try downloading the URL manually using the `InputStream` (`URL.openStream()`) and see if you're getting some kind of response other than an image binary.

**UPDATED**

After investigation, found to be a problem with Java 7 and IPv6 as documented here [Downloading files using Java randomly freezes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650375/downloading-files-using-java-randomly-freezes)

Comment: I have also tried using InputStreamReader but I get the same result. I also know that Google isn't blocking me, as I run a similar program in C# which works fine.

Comment: Okay, sounds like Java might be getting blocked via the fire wall, are you using Windows and Windows firewall (or any kind of firewall)

Comment: Yes using Windows Firewall.

In my firewall rules it states that Java(TM) Platform SE Library is allowed.

Comment: Okay, quick test, disable the Windows Firewall, run you program, re-enable the Windows Firewall (only after either the program completes or after say 15-20 seconds) :P

Comment: Okay disabled the firewall, still no change.

Comment: Can you download ANYTHING via the URL class (a web page, another image)?

Comment: Actually yes, loading another image off the web works. Does that mean the error is in the Google API?

Comment: Don't know yet. If you're using Java 7, there is a known bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650375/downloading-files-using-java-randomly-freezes

Comment: Just added the line `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");` and it works! Thank you SO much!

Comment: That link was interesting.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Always start and update the GUI on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

---

```
g.drawImage(getaImg(), 0, 0, null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters
```

That comment is very good advice, since a 4 char edit should fix the problem.

```
g.drawImage(getaImg(), 0, 0, this); // Observer is good for asynchronous image load
```